# Portable version control?

Tags: php, mysql, version-control, xampp, portable-applications

Currently I do all of my work off of a flash drive. Keeps things portable, and I'm able to learn web development while I'm at work. Currently I run Portableapps with XAMPP, Notepad++, and Chrome installed on it.

**My question is, does anyone know of a version control system that would work portably on a flash drive?** I just learned about the importance of Version control, and I want to get started, I just need something that will work with my setup.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, the whole thing should be able to run off the flash drive alone on a completely foreign computer. So if I go to Aunt Edna's house for a family get together, I can go on her computer, plug in my flash drive and just go. The Aunt Edna's of the world get very offended if you install anything but solitaire on their fancy new computer. So it can't leave anything behind

Comment: So for anyone that's curious, the answer is: there is none, but you can make stuff work using Darcs or Portable Python and Bazaar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109838/recommend-portable-source-control-setup and [Version control on a 2GB USB drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97850/version-control-on-a-2gb-usb-drive) - the second one has an accepted answer ([darcs](http://darcs.net/) looks good too).

Answer (score 2):

Pick a distributed one.

GIT or Mercurial for example.

Comment: Are these actually portable though? I don't want to have it set up on each computer I use it on. Want to be able to drop it on a completely foreign computer and go

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is a good start. A repository does not need to be stored on any server, you just create it where your data files are. Also, there is a nice interface called [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), which lets you use Mercurial out of Windows Explorer with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding off of Dan's Answer.

Git is almost completely file based. As long as you have the files, it will work the same with any computer (given you have the command line stuff installed).

This is also good if you switch between a GUI Editor and the Command Line, as pretty much everything will stay saved (the files waiting to be committed, for example)

Comment: I think the OP is expecting to not have to install the command line stuff as well. The executables, as well as the repository, should be portable.

Comment: exactly. Whole thing should be able to run off the flash drive alone on a completely foreign computer