# GIT on a USB drive

Tags: windows, git, repository

I want to control versions and keep backups in a pen drive. I installed GIT and work with it. But I m still very new to GIT. I cloned a copy of my working project into the pen drive. Now I want to send new commits or new changes to the repository( cloned project of the pen) by the IDE or GIT gui, and continue a same copy inside the pen. (maintaining a remote server is cost for me as I have limited internet service)

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97850/version-control-on-a-2gb-usb-drive). I want to know how to do it with GIT's gui or Netbeans IDE(as it is more easy and save time).

Answer (score 1):

Simply u have to `commit` the changes and then make a `push`. You can find both command in the GUI.
BTW the GUI launches the same commands as the shell application does, and it works the same, almost without any magic, so you can look reference [here](http://gitref.org/).

Then is easier to learn using CLI than GUI at first times, so i suggest u to learn with it